# Generate HTTP request as string with libcurl

Tags: c++, http, libcurl

Is there a way to generate an HTTP request and convert it to a string, without sending the request, using libcurl?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. libcurl is designed for network transfers and that's what it'll do. It has no easy way to "export" what it sends to a server when performing a request.